# c++11 how to convert legacy class to template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typesafe

I have a legacy class like:

```
class Wrapper{
public:
    Wrapper(void*);
    void* get();
};
```

I want to create a type safe wrapper like:

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper{
public:
    Wrapper(T);
    T get();
};
```

Stuff like this won't work because of C++11:

```
template<class T = void*> //Here I would need <>
class Wrapper...

typedef Wrapper<void*> Wrapper; //This isn't allowed
```

Is there a way to convert Wrapper to a template class without editing all places where it's already used?

Comment: In C++17, there is [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) which allow omission of `<..>` is some places.

Comment: Whereas you modernize your code, you might use `using` instead of `typedef`: `using Wrapper = WrapperT<void*>;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to change at other places, you can give your templated class a different name (because you don't even use it then in the first place):

```
template<typename T>
class WrapperT
{
public:
    WrapperT(T t) : _T(t) {}
    T get() { return _T; }
private:
    T _T;
};

using Wrapper = WrapperT<void*>;
```

If you then removed every usage of `Wrapper` you can rename `WrapperT`